# Change input text to a symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start out by saying that I do not know Java Script. I work for a travel agency and I work in content creation & design. I have done minor script work using Sabre Scribe in Eclipse. If people have recommendations on where to go to learn the basics of this, that'd be great. **Edit: This is using program Adobe Captivate Execute Javascript Function.**

Anyways, my goal right now is change a key-press into a symbol. I need to turn "'" into "‡". I am more than happy to put in the time to learn and research this, but all the research I have done has not got me any closer to finding a solution. I have, however, learned how to create an alert when that key is pressed, I just can't seem to get that key to type a different one.

Long story short, I would appreciate some resources or help in the matter.

Comment: Update: I have found a code on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/4/) that works, however I can't delete the key pressed and it also moves my box. Anything is better than nothing right now, but if someone has a solution, let me know! I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Captivate seems to have its own unique flavour of Javascript. After reading the common-js-interface page, something like this may work - can you try it as a test (I don't have the program)??

```
window.cpAPIEventEmitter.addEventListener("CPAPI_VARIABLEVALUECHANGED", function(e) {
    var value = window.cpAPIInterface.getVariableValue("myTextBox");
    value += 'testing';
    window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue('myTextBox', value);
}, 'myTextBox');
```

Of course change all places it says 'myTextBox' to the name of your text field variable.

If this works then I can probably figure out some code to change the ' to that symbol.

Comment: From the looks of that, you are trying to change the text in that box to "testing", correct? That will work for captions and images if the variables are the same, but that won't work for boxes where you must enter the text yourself.

Comment: OK. Sorry I am out of ideas. Best of luck.

Comment: I understand, I'm about at that limit myself and might have to tell my boss I've exhausted all research options and I can't find the solution. On an update, though, when I modified the script portion to:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#cross').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 222) {
  $(this).val($(this).val() + '‡');
  e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
});`
I was no longer able to type in '. It didn't change the input, but it would let me type any other letter. Is there another function that could input text?

Comment: Interesting. So it is half working, just need to get the value though. Instead of the this.val(this.val) what happens if you change that line to e.target.value += '‡';

Comment: You are a bloody genius! It works PERFECTLY. I swear, if you ever need help with travel, you let me know!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

#### This response is invalid for reasons stated in the comments. I'm leaving this up for the comment history. It could very well be of help to others as well.

You'll want to do a search and replace (using regex) on the input's `onkeyup`. You can then swap out the appropriate values using a hash, and replace the value back into the input.

Here's some code I wrote around a week ago that does just that:

```
// note: this needs to be escaped *here*
const hotSwapVals = {
    ':music:': '♫',
    ':rocket:': '',
    ':sat:': '',
    ':satellite:': ''
};

// swap out text with emoji on an input
function hotSwap(obj) {
    if(obj.constructor !== HTMLInputElement)
        throw 'Object must be HTMLInputElement';

    // must be escaped prior, otherwise errors will occur
    const regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(hotSwapVals).join('|'), 'g');

    const val = obj.value.replace(regex, key => hotSwapVals[key]);
    if(obj.value != val)  // prevents moving cursor to end if not needed
        obj.value = val;
}
```

This is then bound to the object by passing the input object as a parameter.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I don't believe something like this will work for what I am using it for. I am using this for a program called Adobe Captivate where I am executing Javascript upon entering a slide. I have a box for text entry where the user must type in information. I need that box to automatically change the " ' " to the "‡".

Comment: You should have specified that in the original question. It's an entirely different question now that you've stated that ─ I've no knowledge of how Adobe Captivate works, and you haven't provided any examples, so it will be difficult to figure out to say the least.

Comment: I do apologize, I did state that I knew little about this coming into this - that is why I am turning to forums for support in terms of where I can find the correct resources to point me in the right direction. I do appreciate you posting, nonetheless.

Comment: Can you at least edit your post to prevent others from thinking the same as I did?

Comment: A simple example based on @jhpratt's answer on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dacozufelo/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks @JonSaw. I'm using it in production and it's well tested over the past week or so. It's seen some use an is relatively efficient.

Comment: @jhpratt: I have edited the post. I knew JS was extremely versatile, but I had no idea how specific it could be. Hence why I am currently trying to learn.

Comment: @TristanHeintzelman I'm pretty sure the concepts shown here should get you started with some minor tweaks on Adobe Captivate.

Comment: @JonSaw: I have been able to set up alerts, which is half of the battle (albeit from my understanding, easiest) part of the battle for me. I've been searching for days and trying so many different things. Any links to information pages or web classes would be handy. There so much out there that it's hard to find what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This code will change the ' character to the symbol when you press the key...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="textField" type="text"></input>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('#textField').on('keydown', function(e) {
                    //console.log(e.keyCode);   // Will tell you the code for the key pressed.
                    if (e.keyCode == 222) {
                        e.target.value += '‡';   // Add the symbol
                        e.preventDefault();   // Stop the single quote from being added.
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am assuming the ('#textfield') needs to be replaced with the variable I have named the text field, is this correct?

Comment: Yes change that to the ID of your text field.

Comment: I have modified that to the name of my text field with no result - nothing happens upon entering the slide and typing a '. After days trying to get answers with Adobe, all I got was "$('body').on('keypress', func )".

Currently, I'm at a loss of where to go now. It seems everything I try fails other than alerts for some reason. Not sure if this helps: https://helpx.adobe.com/captivate/using/common-js-interface.html